# From a scratch table, insert ONLY rows that don't exist in a new table. PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that contain the same columns. One is a scratch table that I need to use as an intermediate data holder and the other one is my final table.

```
CREATE TABLE scratch_table (
    a text,
    b text
);

CREATE TABLE final_table (
    a text,
    b text
);
```

scratch_table has these three rows:

```
  a        |  b
-----------|------------
'text a 1' | 'text b 1'
'text a 2' | 'text b 2'
'text a 3' | 'text b 3'
```

and final_table has two rows:

```
  a        |  b
-----------|-----------
'text a 1' | 'text b 1'
'text a 4' | 'text b 4'
```

I need to write a query that takes ALL the rows in scratch_table and inserts ONLY THOSE THAT DON'T EXIST in final_table. At the end of final_table should be:

```
  a        |  b
-----------|-----------
'text a 1' | 'text b 1'
'text a 2' | 'text b 2'
'text a 3' | 'text b 3'
'text a 4' | 'text b 4'
```

Only the row `'text a 4','text b 4'` was inserted from scratch_table into final_table because it did not exist before.

Please not that the numbers (1-4) that I've used don't indicate any sort of order, I just want to differentiate the data on each row. Thanks!

Comment: do you intentionally paired value in a and b columns? is it OK just to check one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EXCEPT operator is ANSI SQL. It takes two sets and returns only rows from the first set that do not exist in the second set.

```
INSERT INTO final_table (a,b)
SELECT a, b
FROM scratch_table

EXCEPT

SELECT a, b
FROM final_table
```

The EXCEPT operator will return only distinct rows. If you don't want to remove duplicates use `EXCEPT ALL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this, here's one using `not exists`:

```
insert into final_table
select a, b 
from scratch_table st
where not exists (
    select 1
    from final_table ft
    where ft.a = st.a and ft.b = st.b
)
```

This will insert any record from the `scratch_table` that don't exist in `final_table`, matching on both the `a` and `b` fields.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b668/1)

Comment: Thanks! Now, my actual tables have 13 rows. I only used a small table with 2 rows here to illustrate my case. The answer you gave me works perfectly but I'd need a lot of ANDs (13!). I'm sorry I didn't specify this before. Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the same result?

Comment: @LuisC -- I'm not sure I'm understanding?  Why would you need 13 `And` clauses?  `SELECT 1` doesn't mean select the first row, it just means select if it matches (you can just as easily say `select *`).  It should work for your entire table.

Comment: @LuisC -- BTW, here's a good read about the performance difference between `except` and `not exists` (along with a couple other methods).  http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join